# Using Ui forms:Dynamic Dialogs(runtime) vs adding ui through uic(compile time)

Tags: qt, designer, qt-designer

I want to know which way is efficient if I am having number of UI forms. I don have any idea about memory utilization in both of case I just tried both ways in a simple example.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html here they described both ways. 
Now which one method is more efficient?

Comment: I have posted same question again and I got right response there I couldn't delete this post btw. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892944/ui-forms-add-runtime-or-compile-time

Answer (score 1):

```
I want to know which way is efficient if I am having number of UI forms
```

Take a look at this thread: [Hand Coded GUI Versus Qt Designer GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/387092/1758762) (Hand Coded GUI Versus Qt Designer GUI)

```
I don have any idea about memory utilization in both of case
```

This is the same in both cases. Apart from that you don't need to care of it if your class is derived from QObject.

Comment: I am not talking about hand coded and designer GUI but only designer UI forms.

Answer (score 0):

UI files are just a simpler way to generate more Qt correct layouts. It's also much easier to work with designer than to hand code your UI and designer allows for previewing your changes so no generation and compilation needed in most cases. Also, designer allows you to insert your custom widgets using the "Promote to..." option in the context menu for each widget.

The net result of designer code may look messier but it's exactly the same as you manually laying out and is much less prone to error.

Comment: please read question again and i added a link of dynamic dialog your answer is irrelevant of question